# How can I make a line chart without visible axis that fully fills its view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, ios-charts

I have a chart which is styled like so, but the chart does not fill the view, it seem to maintain a spacing between the edges, as if to allow for the axis labels to be drawn.  How can I force the chart portion to take the full size of the Charts view?

When inspecting the view the LineChartViews size is expected, its just that there is a noticeable spacing between the graph and the view, its inset and I cant seem to figure out to to prevent that.

```
self.chartView = [[LineChartView alloc] init];
self.chartView.delegate = self;
self.chartView.chartDescription.enabled = NO;

self.chartView.chartDescription.enabled = NO;
self.chartView.dragEnabled = NO;
self.chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = NO;
self.chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = NO;
[self.chartView setScaleEnabled:NO];
[self.chartView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

ChartYAxis *leftAxis = self.chartView.leftAxis;
leftAxis.axisMaximum = minVal.doubleValue;
leftAxis.axisMinimum = maxVal.doubleValue;
leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;
leftAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = NO;
leftAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = NO;
leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = NO;
leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = NO;

self.chartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = NO;
self.chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;
self.chartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = NO;

self.chartView.rightAxis.enabled = NO;

self.chartView.legend.form = ChartLegendFormLine;
self.chartView.legend.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out with some trial and error.

self.chartView.minOffset = 0;